# iOS erase and get back part of image

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics

I want to make functionality Erase and Paint mode in my app. So user can erase part of image then change the mode and get it back. But yet don't know how to start and impelment it with Core graphics. Please help

Comment: This sort of open-ended "I want to <xyz>, please show me how" question is not a good fit for SO. You need to do some work yourself.

Comment: To get you started, take a look at CALayers, and specifically the mask property of CALayer. You could install a layer as a mask of an image view's layer, and then install an image into the mask and let the user draw into that image. Masking hides part of an image, but doesn't actually erase it.

Comment: yes @DuncanC exactly, also I mean to use masks and how you said not actually erase the image. I have already made some work, but still can't achieve the result. I can't combine two modes and need help :)

Comment: So edit your question and post your code, or at least a description of your approach, and where you're stuck. Your question is too broad as written.